# Empty list progress bar won't disappear

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and a progress bar. I thought it was enough to specify the id as `@+id/android:empty` which would remove the progress bar when the list is populated. However, it is still there after population. Is there a reason it won't be removed or do I need to specify `emptyListView` programmatically?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical" >    

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

(Look at the id attribute)

Comment: No luck. I did it programmatically and it works. I guess I'll stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

It is `@id/android:empty` not `@+id/android:empty`

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"/>
```